# Find number of years it takes for an amount of money in a bank to pass a certain number with yearly deposit

Tags: python, loops, math, while-loop

> First of January each year, Keven puts an amount of 10000 in a bank with an interest rate of 1.8 %. The first deposit was 01.01.2020.
> Make a Python program that calculates the number of years it takes for the amount of money to pass a certain number K. The input should be yearly deposit, interest rate, and K.The output should number of years.

I tried with while loop but got infinite loop.

```
P=1.8      # Interest rate
D=10000     # Yearly deposit
K=250000
n=0         # n:number of years
A=D         # A:amount of money in the bank
while A<=K:
 n=n+1
 D=+A
 A=D*(1+1.8/100)  # Exponential growth
print(n)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If deposit is added before calculation of interest (as your code shows):

```
while A <= K:
    n+=1
    A = (A + D) * (1 + P/100)
```

If deposit is added after calculation of interest:

```
while A <= K:
    n+=1
    A = A * (1 + P/100) + D
```

both variants do work (they give same answer 20 for given data but differ for another input)

Your mistake is here

```
D=+A 
# but yearly deposit is constant

A=D*(1+1.8/100)  # Exponential growth
#we should update current amount A with interest
```